# Responsivo no PC mas não no tablet ou telemóvel

Tags: html, css

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
background-image: url("../assetsimages/book.jpg");
background-size: 100% auto;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
max-width:auto;
height: auto;
```

Como podem ver no tablet e telemovel não está responsivo e não entendo o porque.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para o background ficar com 100% da altura vc também precisa definir a altura no HTML. Também sugiro usar o `background-size` como `cover`. Link com a documentação: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Nesse exemplo abaixo vc pode ver que a imagem sempre fica com 100% da altura ocupa a largura do dispositivo sem perder a "proporção"

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background-image: url(https://www.digitaltrends.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/open-book.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Imagem do resultado no Chrome DevTools simulando o background em dispositivo móvel.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: funcionou.obrigado

Comment: Isso ai é background responsivo, o resto irá continuar não responsivo.

Comment: @Sveen pelo código postado junto com a pergunta presumi que seria sobre o background. Se fosse para ser a página inteira acredito que teria o restante do código na pergunta... Inclusive fique a vontade para responder como vc achar melhor, o autor pode mudar a aceitação da resposta sempre que ele quiser caso apareça algo que ele julgue que atendeu melhor o que ele precisava. Existem perguntas por ai com mais de 10 respostas.

Comment: Não estou tirando o mérito seu, eu também pensei nisso, mas olha https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/286307/texto-não-responsivo-html

Comment: @Sveen pode parecer estranho, mas o que ele fez está absolutamente certo! Segundo as regras do STOF é indicado que não se faça mais de uma pergunta ao mesmo tempo. Ele fez uma pergunta para o BG, agora uma para as outras coisas que precisa. Melhor do que fazer uma pergunta com várias coisas para responder ao mesmo tempo. Depois de uma olhada aqui, tem vários debates sobre esse ponto https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/