# texto não responsivo html

Tags: html, css

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tanto o titulo `<h1>` como o parágrafo `<p>` não consigo colocá-lo responsivo.

**Código:**

```
#h1{
    color:#3396ff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 36%;
    top: 70px;
    text-align:center;
}

#p{
    position: absolute;
    top: 140px;
    left: 35%;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: Procure sobre media queries, a medida em porcentagem não ajuda muito, pois se trata da porcentagem dos pixeis e não do tamanho real da tela.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

Comment: Diana existem alguns estilos no seu CSS que aparentemente são desnecessários, veja os detalhes na minha resposta. Porém se não te atender vou te pedir que edite a sua resposta com o código completo para eu poder te dar uma resposta precisa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sem o restante do código fica difícil ter certeza que essa resposta vai te atender. Mas o que posso dizer é que `position:absolute` com `left:35%` não é o jeito ideal, da forma que está dificilmente vai ficar alinhado em todas as telas.

Para alinhar o texto em 90% dos casos apenas um `text-align:center` vai resolver.

**Exemplo um com `text-align:center`**

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
#h1{
    color:#3396ff;
    top: 70px;
    text-align:center;
}
#p{
    top: 140px;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="h1">Meu título aqui</h1>
<p id="p">Meu paragrafo aqui</p>
```

*Se a resposta não resolver seu problema deixe um comentário que posso te ajudar. Mas ai vou precisar que vc edite seu código com o código completo para eu poder te dar uma resposta mais precisa.*